Using Emacs for Latex and Bibtex and getting "You should run BibTeX to get citations right"
I have recently decided to use Emacs for LaTeX compilation in Windows, using AUCTeX for directly compiling and DocView for viewing, inside Emacs itself.
It was all working until I needed to put bibliography in the .tex file with BibTeX.
creating a .bib file with the citations and putting both \usepackage{cite} and putting at the end of my .tex file \bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{References} (where References.bib is my BibTeX file for the citations). Firstly when running LaTeX in Emacs I got a message about a unreferenced citation, then after reading posts here in tex.stackexchange I used the command C-c C-n and put (setq TeX-auto-save t) (setq TeX-parse-self t) into my .emacs file, but now I get a message with "You should run BibTeX to get citations right, {1} page" in the Emacs buffer. How do I do this? I never had to explicitly run BibTeX in my old editor to make this work.

How do you generally run LaTeX to get the output pdf?  Do you use an Emacs command, or a command line?

I was just using the Emacs/AUCTeX icon for compilation and preview, but now that I used C-c C-a for compilation and C-c C-1 for viewing it worked! Why is that? isn't the icon simply an shortcut for typing C-c C-a ?

C-c C-c and then arrow down on your keyboard some times until you see bibtex as command in the minibuffer.
